# Can't draw rotated image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, rotation

I can't draw my rotated image on top of another image. I tried several ways to do that, but with no success. My backgroundImg is alright, but my logoImageView is not rotated. Why? Here is my code:

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(555, 685);
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[backgroundImg.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 555, 685)];

CGAffineTransform rotate;
rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((rotationSlider.value + 360) * M_PI / 180.0);
logoImageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake (0.5, 0.5);
logoImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale (1, -1);
[logoImageView setTransform:rotate];
```

Then I try 1):

```
   [logoImageView.image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(logoImageView.center.x, logoImageView.center.y)];
```

And 2):

```
[logoImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, logoImageView.bounds.size.width * 2.20, logoImageView.bounds.size.height * 2.20) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1];
```

Finishing the drawing like this:

```
imageTwo = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Neither works - my logoImageView is not rotated. What's the problem? I want my logoImageView.image to be rotated in the combined image.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing here is setting the `transform`-property of `logoImageView`. This property specifies the transform applied to the `UIImageView` itself. While this will make the image appear rotated when the image view is displayed, it doesn't change the underlying image.
So when you rotate the image view and read the `image`-property of your image view, you still get the exact same image as you assigned to it since the transform is applied to the view and not to the image itself.

What you want to do is draw the image to the `CGContext` with a rotated transform. To set this transform you have to use the the `CGContextRotateCTM` function. This function sets the 'Current Transformation Matrix' which specifies the transform to be applied when drawing in the context. I also use `CGContextTranslateCTM` to move the image to the center of the context.

The final code may look like this:

```
CGSize newSize = [flowersImage size];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[flowersImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];

CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), newSize.width / 2.f, newSize.height / 2.f);
CGContextRotateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -M_PI/6.f);

[appleImage drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.f - [appleImage size].width / 2.f, 0.f - [appleImage size].height / 2.f)];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is not working. My logo is upside down, and it is bigger than its original size. Any ideas?

Comment: You can fix the logoImageView being bigger than its original size by changing this line: `[[logoImageView image] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, newSize.width, newSize.height)];` to this: `[[logoImageView image] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, [[logoImageView image] size].width, [[logoImageView image] size].height)];`   
And for the upside down.. I thought that was what you wanted to achieve: drawing  the logo upside down in the combined image? Or perhaps I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I have a background picture, and on top of it I want to draw an image which is rotated by 30 degrees. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry, I indeed missed a part of your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: Okay, but it's not drawing at the right position. Before drawing, i am  positioning the logo with drag and drop. But when i draw it, it goes some pixels away in different directions every time.

Comment: When you say you're positioning the logo using drag 'n drop, I assume you're positioning the `logoImageView` in Interface Builder?
Is it the `logoImageView` in the view hierarchy that moves to a different location every time or the logo you draw in the context?
If it's in the view hierarchy, there could be an Auto Layout constraint missing.
If you want to set the position of the image that gets drawn in your context, you can set the `tx` and `ty` parameters of `CGContextTranslateCTM`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37279/discussion-between-scourginho-and-s1m0n)